# Задание ширины блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, header, выравнивание

Есть сайт https://krasnodar.rbt.ru/?utm_referrer=https%3a%2f%2fwww.yandex.ru%2f. В шапке этого сайта есть следующие блоки city (город), betweencityandheaderinfo (блок из пробелов) и headerinfo (содержит номер телефона 88006003900 (круглосуточно), Доставка, Оплата, Помощь и Скидки и акции).

1. Как задать ширины подблокам блока headerinfo, так чтобы текст подблока был прижат к правому краю подблока (т.е. текст Доставка, Оплата, Помощь и Скидки и акции должны распологаться так, чтобы они были прижаты к правому краю блока, в котором они находятся) ?
2. Есть какой-то блок (div). Как текст внутри него разместить по его центру?

Comment: самый простой способ изучить `css`

Answer (score 1):

1.Присваиваете общий `class` всем подблокам, прописываете в свойствах `css` у этого класса `width:100px;` `float:right;`.
2.В свойствах `css` у этого дива добавляете `text-align:center;`